# how to center mouse pointer on the fillRect() using canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm working with this application using canvas [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw6xD/) as you can see as you move the mouse on the canvas a black rectangle follows the pointer, and the pointer is on the top left of that rectangle. What i want to achieve is just to center the pointer on that rectangle, this is my code

**HTML**

```
<section id="main">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #aaa;"></canvas>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function firstMethod() {
    var cv = document.getElementById('canvas');

    canvas = cv.getContext('2d');    

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", animate, false);   
}

function animate(ev) {
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    var xPos = ev.clientX;
    var yPos = ev.clientY;

    canvas.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 100, 100);
}

window.addEventListener("load", firstMethod, false);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, i just put -50 to xPos and yPos to make it center. since the dimension you've set on the `fillRect()` is 100 x 100

```
function animate(ev) {
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    var xPos = ev.clientX;
    var yPos = ev.clientY;

    canvas.fillRect(xPos-50, yPos-50, 100, 100);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5t7mR/)